# Storing and getting values from sharedpreferences in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to store values in sharedpreferences and getting values from sharedpreferences finally display the values in listview. Next I want to remove values from list when click on longpress on specific value .After removing values status updated in sharedpreferences. i done this one but problem is when close application and open again i have to display  sharedpreferences vales in listview. but it display `NullPointerExeption`,

actually my requirement is 1)storing values in sharedpreferences and display values in listview for every click .allowed only five values.And that list values are available in onresume() method also.
2) when long press on specific value of listview it have to remove and and updated values are stored in sharedpreferences also.

my code

```
public class ListViewDemo1 extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    Button btn;
    static int count;
    private ListView list;
    public static ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();        
    ArrayList countList = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayAdapter adapter;
    SharedPreferences shared;
    Editor editor;
    private static ArrayList<String> sharedList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        shared = this.getSharedPreferences("Myprefernces", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
        editor = shared.edit();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sharedList = new ArrayList();
                count++;
                if (count == 1) {
                    values.add("one");
                    countList.add(count);
                }
                if (count == 2) {
                    values.add("two");
                    countList.add(count);
                }
                if (count == 3) {
                    values.add("three");
                    countList.add(count);
                }
                if (count == 4) {
                    values.add("four");
                    countList.add(count);

                }
                if (count == 5) {
                    values.add("five");
                    countList.add(count);
                }
                if (count > 5) {
                    --count;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + count, 100).show();
                }
                //put values to sharedpreferences
                editor.putInt("SIZE", values.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
                    editor.putString("addr" + i, values.get(i));
                }
                editor.commit();
                // getting values from sharedpreference
                int size = shared.getInt("SIZE", 0);
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                    sharedList.add(shared.getString("addr" + k, ""));
                }
                adapter = new
                        ArrayAdapter(ListViewDemo1.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sharedList);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                           int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                --count;
                values.remove(arg2);
                sharedList.remove(arg2);
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                editor.putInt("SIZE", sharedList.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < sharedList.size(); i++) {
                    editor.putString("addr" + i, sharedList.get(i));
                }
                editor.commit();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (sharedList.size() > 0) {
            adapter = new
                    ArrayAdapter(ListViewDemo1.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sharedList);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.views/com.views.ListViewDemo1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at com.views.ListViewDemo1.onResume(ListViewDemo1.java:114)
04-21 09:56:02.142: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
```

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: Where occur your NullPointerException?

Comment: Because you are not setting the sharedpreference value in the list i cannot see you have passed your sharedpreference values in adapter. All i am seeing is you passed `sharedList`

Comment: please see above log cat

Comment: sharedList = new ArrayList();  
plz intialise outside the listener

Comment: getting values values from sharedprefernce and again added in sharedList and display in listvew

Comment: if i created there ,when i click on button on first time the value came and if click second time the value come with previous value also.but i want only one value for every click

Answer (score 1):

You instantiate `sharedList` only in `onClick()` method of a button. This method is not called when your activity is resumed and `sharedList` is null.

You need to check if it's not null:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if(sharedList != null && sharedList.size()>0){
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter(ListViewDemo1.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,sharedList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually he wants to get the values from sharedpreferences in on resume also

Comment: if i created in onCreate(),when i click on button on first time the value came and if click second time the value come with previous value also.but i want only one value for every click

Comment: when click on button only

Comment: I don't think you read them anywhere. You need to read them in onResume.

Comment: but i want to use sharedList in onResume because it is coming from sharedprefernces

Comment: The values in sharedList are not persisted and are lost (that's why it becomes null). You need to read them again.

Comment: ya i am getting values from sharedprefernce in on resume also but here my problem is if i create object in on resume ,the  prevoius values are added to clicked value when clic on button

Comment: @Override
    protected void onResume() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onResume();
      arr= new ArrayList();
     int size= shared.getInt("SIZE", 0);
  for(int k=0;k<size;k++){
   arr.add(shared.getString("addr"+k,"" ));
  }
  adapter=new ArrayAdapter(ListViewDemo1.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
 
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51076/discussion-between-durga-and-szymon)

Answer (score 0):

The problem i think is with initialization(or rather not doing that),

```
static int count;
public static ArrayList<String>  values = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> sharedList;
```

Now for eg, not initialized count to a value before:

```
count++;  
if(count==1){
```

Same needs to be done for `sharedList`, like `new ArrayList`...

And yes, the reason being `onCreate()` is not called before `onResume()` every time, for more on the refer [Android Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)
Check Figure 1. The activity lifecycle. on that link.

It will give you a better idea for your implementation/requirement and how to initialize or work with `sharedPref` and other components for your activity.

Comment: why we should use `static` in this case ?

Comment: its his code and requirement for implementation :) , i just pointed out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

read this I hope help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You can use SharedPreferences:

To save data:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("text", mSaved.getText().toString());
 editor.putInt("selection-start", mSaved.getSelectionStart());
 editor.putInt("selection-end", mSaved.getSelectionEnd());
 editor.commit();
```

To retrieve data:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
```